# Javascript regex formatter for now allowing a number having , and . at the same time

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers

i'm having an amount input field.
This field must accept only number. For this purpose i use this regex expression:
`amount.toString().match(/[a-z]/i)`. The field also allows decimal seperator with . or , For example the number 1004.23 or 1004,23 is allowed. But if the user enters a number with thousands and decimal seperators this case must be prevented. For example a number like 1,000.14 must not be allowed. How to implement this?

Comment: `amount.toString().match(/[a-z]/i)` matches only one character and no numbers at all

Comment: Yes, i know i user "!" for my case

Comment: are `123.` and `.123` allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can require only digits, then *optionally* a single `,` or `.` followed by digits (so you don't end up with one at the end):

```
/^\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?$/
```

(The `(?:....)` is a non-capturing group, the entire contents of which are optional.

Then use that with `test`:

```
if (/^\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?$/.test(amount)) {
    // It's good
} else {
    // It's not
}
```

No need for `toString`, `test` will do that if appropriate.

Example:

```js
function check(str) {
  return /^\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?$/.test(str);
}
function test(str) {
  console.log(str, "- Allowed:", check(str));
}

test("1004.23");
test("1004,23");
test("1004");
test("1004.");
test(",1004");
test("1,000.14");
```

Of course, you still won't know whether they intend `,` or `.` to be a decimal or thousands separator.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It might have been valid as it was, assuming an ending DP is acceptable.  My assumption would be that we would not want to write it unless there are digits to the right.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Yeah, mine too.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your logic is effectively allowing any number with at most one decimal or comma:

```
^\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?$
```